# Why can't I assign values to my $_SESSION variables?

Tags: php, html

I have a problem that for some reason my `$_SESSION` variables seem to be empty when I am trying to `echo` them onto the form you can see on the picture. The name field ('Név' on the picture) works, however it is from another table from my database.

**Here are the corresponding PHP code snippets:**

*personal.inc.php*:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    require_once 'dbh.inc.php';
    require_once 'getpersonal.inc.php';


    if (isset($_POST["submit_personal"])) {
        $birthdate = $_POST["birthdate"];
        $bio = $_POST["bio"];
        $dailyTime = $_POST["chintime"];
        $favChin = $_POST["favchin"];
        $ownsChinchilla = $_POST["owns_chinchilla"];
        $loveTime = $_POST["year_selector"];
        $userID = $_SESSION["id"];
        $new_name = $_POST["name"];

        $nameUp = "UPDATE user_form SET name='$new_name' WHERE id='$userID'";
        $conn->query($nameUp);

        $checker = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM personal WHERE userID = '$userID'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $checker);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

        if ($row[0] > 0) {
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE personal SET bio = ?, birthDate = ?, dailyTime = ?, loveTime = ?, favChin = ?, owner = ? WHERE userID = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("ssssssi", $bio, $birthdate, $dailyTime, $loveTime, $favChin, $ownsChinchilla, $userID);
        } else {
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO personal (userID, bio, birthDate, dailyTime, loveTime, favChin, owner) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            $stmt->bind_param("issssss", $userID, $bio, $birthdate, $dailyTime, $loveTime, $favChin, $ownsChinchilla);
        }

        getPersonal($conn);

        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();
    }

    header("location: user.php");
    exit();
?>
```

*getpersonal.inc.php*:

```
<?php
    require_once 'dbh.inc.php';

    function dataExists($conn, $userID) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM personal WHERE userID = ?;";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
            header("location: login.php?error=stmtfailed");
            exit();
        }

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $userID);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        $resultData = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultData)) {
            return $row;
        } else {
            $result = false;
        }

        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        return $result;
    }

    function getPersonal($conn) {
        $dataExists = dataExists($conn, $_SESSION["id"]);

        $_SESSION["bio"] = $dataExists["bio"];
        $_SESSION["favChin"] = $dataExists["favChin"];
        $_SESSION["owner"] = $dataExists["owner"];
        $_SESSION["birthDate"] = $dataExists["birthDate"];
        $_SESSION["dailyTime"] = $dataExists["dailyTime"];
        $_SESSION["loveTime"] = $dataExists["loveTime"];
    }
?>
```

***HTML***

```
<form method="post" action="personal.inc.php">
                <label>
                    <div class="namer">
                        <span class="identifier">Név:</span>
                        <input class="inner" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Itt módosíthatod a neved..." value="<?php echo $_SESSION["name"];?>">
                    </div>
                </label>
                <label>
                    <div class=dob>
                        <span class="identifier">Születési idő:</span>
                        <br>
                            <input class="inner" type="date" name="birthdate" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["birthDate"];?>">
                    </div>
                </label>
                <label>
                    <div class="bio">
                        <span class="identifier">Bio:</span>
                            <textarea class="inner" name="bio" width=400px height=230px placeholder="Mesélj magadról, hogy jobban megismerhessünk..." value="<?php echo $_SESSION['bio'];?>"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    
                </label>
                <label>
                    <div class=daily>
                        <span class="identifier">Napi csincsillával töltött idő:</span>
                        <br>
                        <select name="chintime" class="inner" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["dailyTime"];?>">
                            <option>Nincs csincsillám</option>
                            <option>Kevesebb, mint 1 óra</option>
                            <option>1-2 óra</option>
                            <option>3-5 óra</option>
                            <option>Több, mint 5 óra</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </label>
                <label>
                    <div class="fav">
                        <span class="identifier">Kedvenc csincsilla a boltunkból:</span>
                        <div class=inner>
                            <select name="favchin" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["favChin"];?>">
                                <option>Mindet imádom!</option>
                                <option>Puffancs</option>
                                <option>Kókusz</option>
                                <option>Hamu</option>
                                <option>Nutella</option>
                                <option>Mochi</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                </label>
                <label>
                    <div class="owner">
                        <span class="identifier">Van csincsillád?</span>
                        <div class=inner>
                            <select name="owns_chinchilla" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["owner"];?>">
                                <option>Nincs</option>
                                <option>Van</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </label>
                <label>
                    <div class="longlove">
                        <span class="identifier">Mióta imádod a csincsillákat?</span>
                        <br>
                            <input class="inner" type="number" name="year_selector" id="year_selector" min="1900" max="2099" step="1" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["loveTime"];?>">
                    </div>
                </label>
                <button class="savebtn" type="submit" name="submit_personal"><i class="fa-solid fa-floppy-disk"></i><span>Mentés</span></button>
            </form>
```

***This is what I expreience right now:***
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbHQI.png

I would like to `echo` the `$_SESSION` variables into my form when they are set in my database, so if the user only updates 1 field, the other fields won't be touched.

***This is how I assigned my `$_SESSION["name"]` variable***

```
function loginUser($conn, $email_log, $password_log) {
        $emailExists = emailExists($conn, $email_log);

        if ($emailExists === false) {
            echo "<script>
                alert('Hiba! Az e-mail cím nem található!');
                window.location.href = 'login.php#log';
            </script>";
            exit();
        }

        $passwordHashed_log = $emailExists["password"];
        $checkPassword = password_verify($password_log, $passwordHashed_log);

        if ($checkPassword === false) {
            echo "<script>
                alert('Hibás jelszó!');
                window.location.href = 'login.php#log';
            </script>";
            exit();
        } else if ($checkPassword === true) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION["id"] = $emailExists["id"];
            $_SESSION["email"] = $emailExists["email"];
            $_SESSION["name"] = $emailExists["name"];
            header("location: elerheto.php");
            exit();
        }
    }
```

Any form of help is appreciated,

Blaise

Comment: Did you use [session_start()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) before your form html?

Comment: Yes, I did. Also, as I have mentioned I have successfully `echo`ed the name of the user. That shouldn't be the problem unfortunately.

Comment: Where do you assign the value to `$_SESSION["name"]`??

Comment: @nacho I have added it to the end of my original question for you. Name is stored in a different data table however!

Comment: session_start() should be at the beginning of your code, not inside a function

Comment: As I have mentioned, that part has **nothing** to do with what I want to `echo`. Completly unrelated

Comment: Please use prepared statements EVERYWHERE.

Comment: It is related because if you open your sessions in a wrong way, you lose your $_SESSION values

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have finally managed to come up with a fix for this porblem.

I initialize my each of my `$_SESSION` variables when the user logs into the site.

***Codewise:***

```
function dataExists($conn, $userID) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM personal WHERE userID = ?;";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
            header("location: login.php?error=stmtfailed");
            exit();
        }

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $userID);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        $resultData = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultData)) {
            return $row;
        } else {
            $result = false;
        }

        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        return $result;
    }
```

```
function loginUser($conn, $email_log, $password_log) {
        $emailExists = emailExists($conn, $email_log);

        if ($emailExists === false) {
            echo "<script>
                alert('Hiba! Az e-mail cím nem található!');
                window.location.href = 'login.php#log';
            </script>";
            exit();
        }

        $passwordHashed_log = $emailExists["password"];
        $checkPassword = password_verify($password_log, $passwordHashed_log);

        if ($checkPassword === false) {
            echo "<script>
                alert('Hibás jelszó!');
                window.location.href = 'login.php#log';
            </script>";
            exit();
        } else if ($checkPassword === true) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION["id"] = $emailExists["id"];
            $_SESSION["email"] = $emailExists["email"];
            $_SESSION["name"] = $emailExists["name"];

            $dataExists = dataExists($conn, $_SESSION["id"]);

            $_SESSION["bio"] = $dataExists["bio"];
            $_SESSION["favChin"] = $dataExists["favChin"];
            $_SESSION["owner"] = $dataExists["owner"];
            $_SESSION["birthDate"] = $dataExists["birthDate"];
            $_SESSION["dailyTime"] = $dataExists["dailyTime"];
            $_SESSION["loveTime"] = $dataExists["loveTime"];

            header("location: elerheto.php");
            exit();
        }
    }
```